# How to add vertical lines between multiple div elements

Tags: html, css

I have multiple div elements and I want to add a vertical line of seperation in between these div's. Below is the html :

```
     <div class="clone_container " >
     <a class="button-link">Clone</a>
 </div>
<div class="clone_container " >
     <a class="button-link">Delete</a>
 </div>
<div class="clone_container " >
     <a class="button-link">Abort</a>
 </div>
<div class="clone_container " >
     <a class="button-link">Pause</a>
 </div>
```

The output I'm looking for is something like this:
    Clone | Delete | Abort | Pause.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a border on the right side of each element (except the last one) using CSS:

```
.clone_container {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

.clone_container:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xE68V/

Answer (score 1):

Simply you may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9jXau/1/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clone_container " >
    <a href='' class="button-link">Clone</a>
</div>
|
<div class="clone_container " >
    <a href='' class="button-link">Delete</a>
</div>
|
<div class="clone_container " >
    <a href='' class="button-link">Abort</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clone_container{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Clone  | Delete  | Abort  | Pause
```

Also you may put the `|` inside another element (`span`) and apply some styles to that ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9jXau/2/)):

**CSS:**

```
span.separator{
    padding:0 2px;
    color:gray;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clone_container " >
    <a href='' class="button-link">Clone</a>
</div>
<span class='separator'>|</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh…

```
Clone | Delete | Abort | Pause
```

Done.

---

Ok, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="clone_container">
    <a class="button-link">Clone</a>
</div>
|
<div class="clone_container">
    <a class="button-link">Delete</a>
</div>
|
<div class="clone_container">
    <a class="button-link">Abort</a>
</div>
|
<div class="clone_container">
    <a class="button-link">Pause</a>
</div>
```

If you want a fancier looking one, you can do it with CSS:

```
.clone_container:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```